# Setup tsconfig path in svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte

Using Svelte and typescript, I would like to use paths for component import.

I have the following `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "public/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es2020",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@environments/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I do

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Home from '@src/home/Home.svelte'
</script>

<style>
  main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
</style>

<main>
  <Home/>
</main>
```

The home point to some svelte internal file =>

[image]

instead of my `Home.svelte`

[image]

It works if I do `import Home from './home/Home.svelte'`
I can't figure out why.

Comment: You need to configure alias also for the bundler. Which do you use? Webpack? Parcel?

Comment: @johannchopin I have no idea, I am using the svelte template and did the command to add typescript support

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I followed your steps, restarted the Svelte extension (command: "Svelte: Restart Language Server") so it knows about my now `tsconfig.json` setup and then it worked.

Comment: *(command: "Svelte: Restart Language Server")* fixed the `.svelte` file extension support for me where only `.ts` files had been detected by vscode previously. I already had the aliases also setup in my web pack bundler (under `resolve`: `alias`)

Answer (score 8):

The svelte template use [rollupjs](http://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) as the bundler. It is used to recursively parse all your files and transpile (compile for Svelte) into a single `.js` file that every browser can understand.

So when you want to use aliases in your `import` you need to tell to the bundler how it as to handle it. You need for that in the `rollup.config.js` file to declare all the aliases like you do in the `tsconfig.json`.

To declare them you will need to install an external package called [@rollup/plugin-alias](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/alias) and use it like that in the `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import path from 'path'

const projectRootDir = path.resolve(__dirname);


export default {
    ...
    plugins: [
        ...
        alias({
            entries: [
                { 
                    find: '@src',
                    replacement: path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src')
                }
            ]
        }),
        ...
    ],
};
```

Now rollupjs is able to resolve all the paths that contain the `@src` alias.

Check [this repo](https://github.com/johannchopin/dummy-svelte-project-with-alias-example) for a working example.

Comment: Any clean way to accomplish this without having to define your aliases in two different locations (here and tsconfig)? I guess import your tsconfig and map over them?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk Yes exactly or you could extract them in a dedicated file. Choose what suits you best ;)

Answer (score 2):

I spend a lot of time to solve this issue. A lot of time...

The only way I finally made it work is a combination of these steps:

1. Setup paths in tsconfig like you did.
2. Install @ropllup-plugin-alias like this (the important part is plugins section -> alias:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import alias from "@rollup/plugin-alias";
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';

import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

import path from "path";

const projectRootDir = path.resolve(__dirname);

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;


export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
    svelte({
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
      dev: !production,
      extensions: [ ".svelte" ],
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write('public/build/bundle.css');
            },
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
    }),

    alias({
      entries: [
        { find: "@src", replacement: path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src') },
        { find: "@layout", replacement: path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/layout') },
        { find: "@public", replacement: path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'public') },
        { find: "@app", replacement: path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/app') },
        { find: "@components", replacement: path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/components') },
        { find: "@util", replacement: path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/util') },
        { find: "@stores", replacement: path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src/stores') }
      ]
    }),

        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
    }),
    
    commonjs(),

    typescript({ sourceMap: !production }), 

        
        !production && serve(),

        
        !production && livereload('public'),

        
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

3. And the last one is... well, it works for me only with specifying the extension.

This one works: `import something from "@app/module.ts";`

This one do not:  `import something from "@app/module";`

I hope it helps in your case too.